# Вынести на заседанИИ(-ИЕ) ?

Tags: орфография

Вынести вопросы на заседание или на заседании?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынести вопрос (из кулуаров, подготовительных комитетов, согласительных комиссий) на заседаниЕ (Верховной Рады). Где он будет обсуждаться и решаться. Непосредственно на заседаниИ (городского совета, парламента) вопросы не выносятся, а вносятся (депутатами) в повестку дня.